# How to Calculate or Integrate this equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm back with another question. This one is about finding the general solution to $y'+3y=3x+5\sin x$. I see this is already in the form where I can find the integrating factor. The integrating factor is $e^{\int 3dx}=e^{3x}$. Next, I multiply this everywhere to the equation: $e^{3x}xy'+e^{3x}y=e^{3x}x+5\sin xe^{3x}$. Now I organize it to $(e^{3x}y)'=3xe^{3x}+e^{3x}5\sin x$. I ask, what is the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done.

$$(e^{3x}y)'=3xe^{3x}+e^{3x}5\sin x$$

Integrate both sides to get

$$e^{3x}y = \int 3xe^{3x}+e^{3x}5\sin x dx +C$$

Then multiply both sides by $e^{-3x}$ to get $y$

$$ y = e^{-3x}\int 3xe^{3x}+e^{3x}5\sin x dx +Ce^{-3x}$$

The integration is done by parts or by a table of integrals.